# nvm installation error - yo: command not found

Tags: software-installation, git, nodejs

I was going to install hubot. When I installed nvm, it failed, and I can't use `nvm -v` to view its version. I don't know the reason why it failed.

Here is the error log:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "generator-hubot"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall script 'nodepostinstall'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the spawn-sync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node postinstall
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs spawn-sync
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spawn-sync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/shi/npm-debug.log

shi@shi-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
/usr/local/lib
└── coffee-script@1.10.0 

shi@shi-VirtualBox:~$ cd myhubot

shi@shi-VirtualBox:~/myhubot$ yo hubot
yo: command not found

shi@shi-VirtualBox:~/myhubot$ cd ..

shi@shi-VirtualBox:~$ yo hubot
yo: command not found
```

Comment: Did you install yeoman ( npm install -g yo )? From the log you provided I cannot see anywhere where you have and then you tried yo hubot

Comment: before that, I installed hubot, and nvm(git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm), and I tried to use npm install -g yo, Unfortunately, that ERR happened....

Comment: When you installed nvm did you also install node using nvm install 6.3.0 or which ever version node you want? I see you sudo npm install for coffee-script which is **very discouraged**

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have installed node v4.2.6,  now I installed nodejs, nvm, hubot, coffee-cript, io.js, and still doesn't work.

Comment: when you use `nvm --version` does it show 0.31.2 which is the lastest nvm, or does it throw an error?

Comment: yeah, it shows 0.31.2, by the way, I use the latest version of Ubuntu 16.04LTS  and I run it on VirtualBox.

Comment: Okay so nvm didn't fail when you installed it, because it would have not shown you the version number.  You  installed node using `nvm install 4.2.6` then you installed hubot using **?** and you install coffee-script using `sudo npm install -g coffescript` does this look correct? Sorry for all the questions before I sumit the answer, I just need to know where you are at now

Comment: Thank you very much, you just remind me the installation of Hubot, and I reinstalled Hubot and it works. Thanks for your all kind reminders!

Comment: Okay if you want to you can accept the answer so other people will see that it is solved without looking through all these comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
nvm install 4.2.6
npm install -g yo generator-hubot
mkdir myhubot && cd myhubot
yo hubot
```

Partial source: [hubot of github](https://hubot.github.com/docs/)