# node:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:version GLIBCXX_3.4.14, GLIBCXX_3.4.18, CXXABI_1.3.5, GLIBCXX_3.4.15, GLIBC_2.17, GLIBC_2.16 and GLIBC_2.14 not found

Tags: command-line, nodejs, glibc, gnu

While running

```
node -v
```

it shows the below error:

```
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error now fixed, I have installed nvm from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797623/nvm-installation-error-yo-command-not-found) and then when i run

> nvm -v

Issue remains same as i said in my question

After that doing this from [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found?answertab=active#tab-top) it got fixed
But same error came when i gave exit and run same command...
So i followed some steps from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/) and i run below commands

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Even though i got same error on some points while run version change commands.
So after taught version may be problem.
Then i ran to set default version to

```
nvm -ls # to list versions we installed(here also mention default and LTS versions)

nvm alias default 10.5.0
```

If no version 10.5.0, we should install.

```
nvm install 10.5.0
```

And then excute above export command... Then its working fine